# Partially hide flanking divs on resize

Tags: css, html, screen-resolution

After nearly an hour of searching, and another hour experimentation, I can't seem to find how to do this in CSS/HTML.

Given the following image where the blue box is a div holding the page's primary content at a fixed pixel width, the red boxes are divs holding decoration at a fixed pixel width, and the black line shows the browser size:

[image: example of browser sizes with div boxes]

- A - Would **not** feature a horizontal scroll bar as nothing is hidden. Everything is centered.
- B - Would **not** feature a horizontal scroll bar as only the side divs are hidden. The main div is centered.
- C - **Would** feature a horizontal scroll bar as now the main div can't fit on the page. the main div is center, and it shouldn't be possible to scroll to see the side divs.

I want to add extra decoration to the page without hurting it for users with smaller screen resolutions or simply upon window resize. The main div will hold the primary content, so the user should be able to scroll to see it all. On the other hand, the side divs are there only for decoration, so the browser shouldn't scroll based on them. I'd rather not set the side divs instead up as a background image as I'd like increased freedom beyond this.

It *seems* like this should be possible. Is it? I've been playing around with overflow but I can't get anything to work.

(To be clear, this is about horizontal centering/scrolling, not vertical)

Answer (score 2):

You should use the CSS: `overflow: hidden;` to achieve this effect. Have two divs, one longer, and another with a fluid width.

```
.parent {width: 90%; overflow: hidden;}
.parent .child {width: 1200px; margin: auto;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use percentage value to achieve this

HTML

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="d1"></div>
    <div class="d2"></div>
    <div class="d3"></div>
</div>​
```

CSS

```
.outer{wisth:100%;border:solid 1px black; padding:25px}
.d1{background:red; width:32%; height:60px; display:inline-block}
.d2{background:green; width:32%; height:60px; display:inline-block}
.d3{background:blue; width:32%; height:60px; display:inline-block}
```

​**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/P8WLL/1/)**